# Laravel Save Method Isn't Updating Record

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In one of my controllers, I am needing to update a specific record in another table. I have code to find the table, update the specific column, and save it. My problem is that the record is never updated. I have ensured that the column is fillable.

Here is the code that is giving me problems:

```
$portfolio = Portfolios::where('id', $request->portfolioID)->first();
$portfolio->totalValue = $portfolio->totalValue + $cd->currValue;
//dd($portfolio);
$portfolio->save();
```

At the die and dump that is commented out, I can compare the attributes shows the correct value and the original value was the previous value, which is still retained after the save.

Comment: This could be due to a host of other factors. One can't tell which may be affecting your implementation just from these lines. Maybe more code will help clear this up.

Comment: This is all the code in this particular function regarding updating the portfolio record. The rest of the code deals with calculating the `$cd->currValue`.

Comment: is anything saving successfully in this controller action?  other models ?

Comment: Move dd outside the process, same result if you dd after save line? Is totalValue fillable?

Comment: @wheelmaker yes the other model is that I am working with saves fine.

Comment: `$fillable` doesn't matter for this, it's only for mass assigment

Comment: short of using something like the DB Transations trait or helpers, I'm not sure how this is possible, posting more code might help, clearly something is going on that's not posted here